# Windows command-line ftp put/upload files older than 1 minute

Tags: ftp, cmd

I have the following batch file:

```
open <ip>
username
password
bin
lcd C:\FTP_OUT\
prompt
mput *.PDF
ascii
mput *.XML
bye
```

How do I change it to upload only files older than 1 minute to the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows `ftp.exe` does not support any kind of a file selection based on a file timestamp.

All you can do is to generate a temporary upload script with an explicit list of files to upload. You can use a PowerShell script to generate the temporary script (implementing in a pure batch file would be very difficult).

---

A way easier solution is to use an FTP client that supports selecting files based on file timestamp.

For example with [WinSCP FTP/SFTP client](https://winscp.net/) you can use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
winscp.com /log=upload.log /command ^
  "open ftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
  "lcd C:\FTP_OUT" ^
  "put *.PDF<1N" ^
  "put -transfer=ascii *.XML<1N" ^
  "exit"
```

The `<1N` in the files mask is [a time-constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) that selects files created or modified more than one minute ago only.

See also the guide for [converting Windows `ftp.exe` scripts to WinSCP scripts](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*